# AMP form amp_source_origin error cors header

Tags: forms, cors, amp-html

I am getting error in AMP Form

```
 <form class="innler-left" method="post" action-xhr="//mydoma.com/ xxxx/xxx/xxx/send.php" target="_top">
```

On submit getting below error in console.

```
Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header
Form submission failed: Error: 
Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​ _reported_
```

Once user submit the form it goes it php file in where I put the following header

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header("access-control-allow-credentials:true");
header("AMP-Same-Origin: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:".$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header("amp-access-control-allow-source-origin: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
header("access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token");
header("access-control-allow-methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

I got it working offline on local machine but once i upload files, it not working :(

tried https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md

POST __amp_source_origin is not matching!

Comment: Could you debug what .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] produces? Is it necessary adding: "https://" in front?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue to fix this, make sure your URL start with `https`. And try to replace the following line in your code :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:".$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
```

with

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ". str_replace('.', '-','https://www.example.com') .".cdn.ampproject.org");
```

***Note :*** *Replace https://www.example.com with your AMP website URL*

Hope it helps.

Comment: @YvetteColomb ! sorry I am not getting your point. Are you asking for `amp-html` tag edits for other posts ?

Comment: Alright @YvetteColomb! Thank You :) I will take care of it